# Compare Table Sizes to Trigger Pipeline in Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure-data-factory

I currently have 2 Lookup Activities that both return total row counts, one for a Temp table and one for a current table that the TEMP will replace. I want to be able to compare these two values, determine if the new table is within 25% of the old tables row count and if it is, to trigger the pipeline to move the tables. I have not been able to do anything with the row counts. I was setting the results at variables, but the dynamic content I add to try and determine the TEMP table size does not work. Any ideas on how I could take the row counts and then turn them in to usable variables in Azure Data Factory?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you can compare the two `Lookup` outputa in one `[if-condition][1]`, then add the active in the true or false condition:

For example, I compare the row count between table `test3` and `test`:

Lookup1: test3 row count:

[image]

Lookup2 test row count:

[image]

Compare the two output row count in `if-condition` active:

I just compare the row count expression test3 > test:

```
@activity('Lookup1').output>activity('Lookup2').output
```

[image]

Then you could add the active to move the table if condition true or false.

The whole pipeline preview:

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: Can the expression be changed to see if the TEMP table is within 25% of the LOAD tables size? This is the configuration I am struggling with.

Comment: @J.Clark  You're right. Expression can not achieve campare if TEMP table is within 25% of the LOAD tables size. I'm sorry.

Comment: No problem. Outside of the comparison in the IF condition, do you know of a possible way to achieve this out put?

Comment: @J.Clark Just according my experience, I think it's impossible. I tried all of the ways I know, all failed.